# Flutter Google Maps Custom Marker With Gifs

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart

I am working on flutter for a project using google maps. I want to use gifs for the markers I will use on the map.

I've run an image with BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage, but when I add a gifs asset path here, the gifs behave like images and don't work.

Is there a way to run gifs on markers?

```
BitmapDescriptor? doneLocationIcon;
BitmapDescriptor? wrongLocationIcon;
```

in initstate code:

```
BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
    ImageConfiguration(devicePixelRatio: 1,size: Size(1,1)),
    'assets/images/done.png').then((onValue) {
  doneLocationIcon = onValue;
});
BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
    ImageConfiguration(devicePixelRatio: 2.5),
    'assets/images/wrong.png').then((onValue) {
  wrongLocationIcon = onValue;
});
```

}

Comment: It looks like you are passing in a `.png` file for your markers. Have you tried using `.gif` files?

Comment: I gave an example with .png in the code I shared, it's my fault. but while trying with gif, I already tried with .gif extension but it didn't work. Google maps does not allow to run widgets on gifs or maps.